# How can I use sed to delete line with square brackets?

Tags: bash, sed, brackets

I have one text file.

```
cat 3.txt
qqq abc cdef (1234) [5689a]
abcfde [aaaa]
ffff [321]
```

this file with brackets content.

```
IFS=$'\n'
VAR=( $(</tmp/3.txt) )
LEN=${#VAR[@]}

for (( i = 0; i <LEN; i++ ));do
    echo ${VAR[$i]}
    sed -i -e "\#${VAR[$i]}#d" /tmp/3.txt
done
```

I want to echo

> qqq abc cdef (1234) [5689a]

then delete this line.
and echo second line. then delete second line.
and echo third line. then delete third line.
but this line with [].How can I use sed to delete this line?

Comment: If you can tell us why you want to do that it'll help us come up with an answer to do whatever it is you need to do the right way. Specifically - why do you want to print-then-delete one line at a time vs printing all the matching lines together and then deleting them all together? Also, come up with an example that better illustrates your problem because right now `cat 3.txt; > 3.txt` will produce your desired output. I suspect this question is an example of [The XY Problem](http://xyproblem.info/).

Comment: If you can, use `readarray -t VAR < /tmp/3.txt` instead of messing around with `IFS`.

Comment: `readarray -t VAR < /tmp/3.txt` will show like this 
`qqq` `abc` `cdef` `(1234)` `[5689a]` `abcfde` `[aaaa]` `ffff` `[321]`

Comment: To process each line of your file you may loop with a simple `while read -r VAR; do echo $VAR; done < /tmp/3.txt`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

IMHO, you can't do it with just one `sed` but below might be an approach

```
$ cat 38680195
qqq abc cdef (1234) [5689a]
qqq abc cdef (134) [4hgh]
line with <angle brackets>
line without brackets
line with {curly braces}
line with [square brackets]
another line without brackets
$ sed -n '/\[[^]]*\]/p' 38680195 && sed -i.backup '/\[[^]]*\]/d' 38680195
qqq abc cdef (1234) [5689a]
qqq abc cdef (134) [4hgh]
line with [square brackets]
$ cat 38680195
line with <angle brackets>
line without brackets
line with {curly braces}
another line without brackets
```

**Note**
A backup of original file is placed in 38680195.backup

```
$ cat 38680195.backup 
qqq abc cdef (1234) [5689a]
qqq abc cdef (134) [4hgh]
line with <angle brackets>
line without brackets
line with {curly braces}
line with [square brackets]
another line without brackets
```

**Edit**

A smarter approach may be

```
grep '\[[^]]*\]' 38680195 && sed -i.backup '/\[[^]]*\]/d' 38680195
```

In this case if none of the lines contain `[]`, the sed part wont be executed because it is logically `AND`ed (See `&&`).

Comment: I want to echo one line and delete one line, so I need to use array, read one line then echo it. If I use `sed -n '/\[[^]]*\]/p' 38680195 && sed -i.backup '/\[[^]]*\]/d' 38680195` It will change every [ ] in file. in next round echo will not print correct value.

Comment: `echo one line and delete one line` ? `delete one line` from where?

Comment: echo first line then delete first line from 3.txt, then echo second line delete second line from 3.txt.

Comment: @MaxWu : That doesn't make much sense to me

Comment: Actually in original scrip , "echo xxx" is "uploading file to somwhere", so when file uploaded, then delete file name in 3.txt.

Answer (score 1):

This is another approach:

```
grep '\[' test.txt; sed "s/^.*\[\+.*$//" test.txt | grep -v '^$';
```

The first grep finds lines with brackets, the second removes those lines and the final grep displays only the lines which are not empty (which are those without brackets).